# How to add some text to selected cells in sheet Google Drive

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

How can I add some text to selected cells in a Google Spreadsheet. Can I perform it by using a regular expressions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes; select the desired cells (they must be contiguous), Ctrl+H (brings up the Find and replace tool).

In Find, type `$`

In Replace with, type `some_text`

Ensure "Specific range" is selected, and check "Search using regular expressions".

Click "Replace all".